# call function variable inside function variable

Tags: php

```
$function = function($parameter) use ($variable)
{
  //Do some stuff
  $function($something); //When I do this i get variable undefined '$function'
}
```

How can I call the function?

I've already tried to call the parent or redefine the variable but i'd like a more compact solution than just redefining a whole new function and using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general trick here is to `use ()` the Closure holding variable by reference:

```
$function = function($parameter) use ($variable, &$function) {
    //Do some stuff
    $function($something);
}
```